# How to keep calculated data in memory for multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, data-transfer

My problem seemed simple to me, but apparently it isn't.

I got a core class that is able to calculate a complex result depending on parameters entered by a user. Up to now I showed the result as a ListView and for the detail view, I used a sliding panel - so everything is neat within one activity A.

But now, I wanted to get rid of the sliding design and "simply" use a master/detail flow so I could show two fragments next to each other on tablets and separately on a mobile phone.

Well, I did not want to redesign the whole app for that, but basically: how do I get the detail information to my different activity B???

I know that through an Intent I can only send Parcelable (or serializable) data, but that is far to complex for essentially int-array-type of data! All the converting to and re-constructing from the Intent - that is just a pain!

Of course, I also do not need a database or similar complicated stuff - no SharedPrefs, please, that is all at least as complex as implementing the Parcelable!

Basically, I thought of two approaches, but they all ... stink ... kind of:
a) store the calculated data within the application class - problem: the app might get destroyed and restarted just for re-displaying activity B. Then there wouldn't be anything left in the app object!
b) implement a content provider that does the calculation and caching the result there. Hmm. The cursor again is way to complex to transfer the simple result. And: for how long should I cache the result in the ContentProvider?

I feel this is all a mess. :-(
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Intent approach is by far the simplest one.
Talking about a Master/Detail flow, usually that means passing one id, this is few information and easily reconstructed from A to B (activity).

Don't use A for exactly the reason you mentioned, and B wow! too much work =)

I really think either use an Intent or use shared Prefs they are by far the least code demanding options.

Comment: Passing an ID as a lightweight intent content works ONLY if the ID is pointing to some data - and my question is exactly where to hold that data...

Comment: @Zordid with your kind of concerns, i think the only true ways of doing this is either store your data on files, or use a database (might be too much depending on the kind of data).

Comment: that would all be MUCH to complicated. I calculate departure times of busses - the detail data is the complete ride, only a few bytes of data, but structured. I would never create a database for that or a flat file. But putting such an object into an intent (which in a sense is nothing but a HashMap for key-value pairs) is overkill, too...

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to create the behavior of the app getting destroyed and everything being deleted? I've been developing an app doing some things along the same lines and I have just been using public static variables to store things in the activity that they are created in. That way they are accessible from other activities. Not necessarily the most elegant way of doing things but it's working for me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

oh man its not mess:)

did you aware of Design patterns if yes then you can use singleton pattern where you can store data for your next activity

```
public class mySingleton 
{
   mySingleton instance;
   yourvariable1;
   yourvariable2;
   yourvariable3;
   yourobject1;
   yourobject2;

  public static mySingleton getSingletonInstance()
    {
      if(instance==null)
        {
          instance=new mySingleton();
        }
      return instance;
    }
}
```

by this you can save your data till your any activity is running or you may say untill your application is in system memory

but if you want to close application and persist data then make a background service there you can save data your applications activities will destroy but the service will contain the variables and data

hope  it will solve your problem

Comment: ...of course I know singletons... :-) But in Android, that's not working because you can never rely on an app (including its singleton classes) still being alive when an activity is brought to front...

Comment: you can start a background service for that which will persist your data

Comment: or if you want to persist data for a long period of time you may write some files on permanent storage and red or write data on that